# $.when apply for single request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use `$.when apply`  in my code. However, it seems that the format return is different for single and multiple request. How can i cater for it?? I am trying not to have another if else outside of it.

```
$.when.apply(null, apiRequestList).then(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
       var value = arguments[0];
    }
});
```

This is what i do not want to do.

```
if (apiRequestList.length === 1) {
    $.ajax({

    });
} else {
    $.when.apply(null, apiRequestList).then(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
           var value = arguments[0];
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what the difference is that you're concerned about.  The object returned from `$.when()` does vary depending on whether single or multiple promises are passed, but AFAIK the resulting parameters passed to the subsequent `.then` callback will always just be a list of the promises' resolved values.

Comment: Just drop `$.when` and use `Promise.all` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply convert `arguments` into an array, when the length of `apiRequestList` is 1:

```
$.when.apply(null, apiRequestList).then(function() {

    var _arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (Array.isArray(apiRequestList) && apiRequestList.length === 1)
        _arguments = [arguments];

    for (var i = 0; i < _arguments.length; i++) {
        var value = _arguments[i][0];
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

[Live Example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfby03pd/2/) (since we can't do ajax on Stack Snippets):

```
function x(a) {
  return $.post("/echo/html/", {
    html: "a = " + a,
    delay: Math.random()
  });
}
function doIt(apiRequestList) {
  $.when.apply(null, apiRequestList).then(function() {

      var _arguments = arguments;
      if (Array.isArray(apiRequestList) && apiRequestList.length === 1)
          _arguments = [arguments];

      for (var i = 0; i < _arguments.length; i++) {
          var value = _arguments[i][0];
          console.log(value);
      }
      console.log("----");
  });
}
doIt([x(1), x(2), x(3)]);
doIt([x(4)]);
```

Example output (it'll vary because of the `Math.random()`):

```
a = 4
----
a = 1
a = 2
a = 3
----
```

Comment: Wouldn't it better: `_arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`?

Comment: @A.Wolff Not necessary, you can iterate over `arguments` just fine